# Libspotify playing problems

Tags: c#, multithreading, interop, spotify

I'm writing a C# wrapper around libspotfiy, and have a problem with the track playing. From what I can tell, when I want to start streaming a track for the first time in a session, I should call

```
sp_session_player_load(sessionHandle, trackHandle)
sp_session_player_play(sessionHandle, true);
```

This is what I'm doing, and it works fine. The problem start when I want to play something else. With a track still playing, what am I meant to do to play a new one? Should I call

```
sp_session_player_play(sessionHandle, false);
sp_session_player_unload(sessionHandle);
```

Before then calling a new round of load/play? I ask because when I do this, I often see my program hang when I call the unload, or call play with an argument of false. I'm using the get_audio_buffer_stats callback. I've got appropriate thread syncronisation in place, so I'm wondering if I'mu sing the api incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the official Mac and iOS library does, and it works fine:

When playing for the first time:

```
sp_session_player_load(sessionHandle, trackHandle)
sp_session_player_play(sessionHandle, true);
```

When playing again:

```
sp_session_player_play(sessionHandle, false);
sp_session_player_unload(sessionHandle);
sp_session_player_load(sessionHandle, trackHandle)
sp_session_player_play(sessionHandle, true);
```

There are a couple of things you can check, though:

- The most common hang I've seen is due to how the program implements the `notify_main_thread` callback. When you get this, you must schedule a call so `sp_session_process_events` on the main thread in a *non-blocking* way. I.e., your `notify_main_thread` implementation should return before `sp_session_process_events` is called on the other thread.
- Try taking out your `get_audio_buffer_stats` implementation. This Mac/iOS library doesn't implement this at all - it isn't required.

If this isn't enough, please try to get a stack trace of the hang. If you catch it in the debugger, hitting pause is often good enough.

Comment: My code reacts to a notify_main_thread callback by simply signalling to another thread, so it's totally non blocking.

Comment: How can I respond to this with more than 600 characters?

Answer (score 0):

My code reacts to a notify_main_thread callback by simply signalling to another thread, so it's totally non blocking.

I seem to have resolved things, but I'm still left a little puzzled. I did indeed remove the get_audio_buffer_stats callback. However, the thing that seemed to help was to stop doing anything in the music_delivery callbacks before calling sp_session_player_unload.

I had a lock around evrything I did in the music_delivery callback, and the same lock protecting the sp_session_player_unload. So it seems that while performing the sp_session_player_unload, another thread inside libspotify would trigger the music_delivery callback, which would naturally have to wait for the sp_session_player_unload to complete. It seems this could cause deadlock.

I thought I was doing the right thing by ensuring that the music_delivery callback and other libspotify functions (ie sp_session_player_unload) should be protected by the same mutex? Perhaps the right thing to do inside the music_delivery is to return immediately, reporting no samples taken if the attempt to get the lock fails? (and would this then be the case for all the callbacks made outside of the process_events thread?)

Comment: Your observations are correct, and your `notify_main_thread` approach is perfectly fine. I'd actually go as far as to say that you shouldn't protect your `music_delivery` with the same mutex as any "main thread" methods at all, including `sp_session_player_unload`.

Comment: Ok, but I don't I need to make sure that no libspotify methods are called during any of the non-main thread callbacks?

Comment: You need to make sure libspotify methods aren't being called at the same time from multiple threads. If your non-main thread callback implementations don't call directly back into libspotify, you can carry on in the main thread at the same time with no problems.